# Alternatives to "case-when" with large number of buckets

Tags: sql, grouping, case-when

In cases where you need to create a large number of buckets, is there a more efficient method than a long case-when statement?

For example, my current query breaks package weight into multiple buckets (i.e. 1-5 lbs, 5-15 lbs) up to 70 lbs.  However, I now need to create 70 different buckets (one for every lbs) where anything weighing between 1-2 lbs will round up to "2 lbs", anything between 2-3 lbs will round up to "3 lbs" etc.  Is there a better way to do this than writing a case-when statement with 70 different criteria?

Here is my current query:

```
    , CASE 
        WHEN round(orders.pkg_bill_weight,5)  < 1
            THEN '<1 lb'
        WHEN round(orders.pkg_bill_weight,5) >= 1
            AND round(orders.pkg_bill_weight,5) < 
            THEN '1-5 lb'
        WHEN round(orders.pkg_bill_weight,5) >= 5
            AND round(dosi.pkg_bill_weight,5) < 15
            THEN '5-15 lb'
        WHEN round(orders.pkg_bill_weight,5) >= 15
            AND round(orders.pkg_bill_weight,3) < 30
            THEN '15-30 lb'
        WHEN round(orders.pkg_bill_weight,5) >= 30
            AND round(orders.pkg_bill_weight,5) < 50
            THEN '30-50 lb'
        WHEN round(orders.pkg_bill_weight,5) >= 50
            AND round(orders.pkg_bill_weight,5) < 70
            THEN '50-70 lb'
        WHEN round(orders.pkg_bill_weight,5) > 70
            THEN '70+ lb'           
        ELSE 'Unknown' END as pkg_weight
```

Comment: So you just need to round up the weight to the next integer? Depending on what RDBMS you are using ([mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling), [sql server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx), [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions017.htm), [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html), etc..) there may be a CEILING formula.

Comment: Thank you, that works great!

Comment: Depending on your RDBMS you could maybe use the pivot clause (in combination with ceiling)